# Does the "Exceptional Attribute" trait only raise the max or also the attribute?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

> [Disclaimer: I only own the German rule book, so my nomenclature might
>   be a bit off.]

During Shadowrun 5e character creation one can buy advantageous traits using karma (or get karma from disadvantageous ones).

One trait is called **exceptional attribute** (or something similar). The description states that this trait allows characters to raise the max of one of their attributes by one, i.e. normally from a six to a seven. The wording of the German edition is fairly ambiguous however...

- Does the trait raise *just* the maximum value of the attribute? (I.e. "Exceptional Strength" on a STR of 6 would still result in having STR 6 with the option of raising STR later), **or**
- Does the trait raise the maximum of the attribute *and* the attributes value (I.e. "Exceptional Strength" on a STR of 6 would result in STR 7, period.)

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt actually state that in the rules? I have the newest german Version at Home and will take a look at it once i am Home.

Comment: It's funny, the German rules state the same thing for *other* traits, like "Lucky" iirc (i.e. the max going up, but the attribute not) - this only added to the confusion as the "Exceptional Attribute" text didn't make mention of this explicitly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Exceptional Attribute doesn't give you any extra point**.

English text goes as follows:

> The Exceptional Attribute quality is how you get to be the charismatic troll or the agile dwarf. **It allows you to possess one attribute at a level one point above the metatype maximum limit.** For example, an ork character with the Exceptional Attribute quality for Strength could take his Strength attribute up to 10 before augmentations are applied, instead of the normal limit of 9. Exceptional Attribute also applies toward Special Attributes such as Magic and Resonance. Edge cannot [be] affected by the Exceptional Attribute (Edge is raised by another quality called Lucky). A character may only take Exceptional Attribute once, and only with the gamemaster's approval.